# Добавить HttpCookie в CookieStore

Tags: java

Возникла необходимость добавить несколько куки в менеджер, для авторизации на сайте. Куки успешно добавляются, но при запросе к сайту их не видно (проверял через fiddler). Написал воспроизводимый пример:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class Main {
    static public void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        CookieManager cookieManager = new CookieManager(null, CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL);
        CookieStore cookieJar = cookieManager.getCookieStore();
        CookieHandler.setDefault(cookieManager);

        HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("name123", "value123");
        cookieJar.add(new URI("http://httpbin.org"), cookie);

        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL("http://httpbin.org/cookies").openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        connection.connect();

        BufferedReader in;
        StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
        String inputLine;
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();
        System.out.println(response.toString());
    }
}
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что я упустил.

Comment: Благодарю! Можете оформить ваше сообщение как ответ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вместе с запросом отправляются только куки для того же домена и с подходящим путем (путь в адресе запроса должен начинаться с пути для куки).

Домен `InMemoryCookieStore` берет из параметра метода `add( uri, cookie )`, а путь должен быть в самом объекте `HttpCookie`. Конструктор `HttpCookie` его не задает, поэтому нужно установить путь отдельно, вызовом

```
cookie.setPath( "/" );
```

Так же желательно установить домен и версию:

```
cookie.setDomain( "httpbin.org" );
cookie.setVersion( 0 ); // не все серверы понимают RFC 2965
```

- [документация api к android](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) содержит пример работы с куки.

Answer (score 2):

Как ни странно, но `CookieManager` не отправляет cookie на сервер. Это надо делать самостоятельно:

```
...
connection.setRequestMethod("GET");

String cookies = String.join(";", cookieManager
                                    .getCookieStore()
                                    .getCookies()
                                    .stream()
                                    .map(HttpCookie::toString)
                                    .collect(Collectors.toList()));

connection.setRequestProperty("Cookie", cookies);

connection.connect();
...
```